# Schema.org structured data for blog category page

Tags: schema.org, blog, categories

Is there any Schema.org type that I should use on my category page of my WordPress blogsite for the blogposts that are listed in the category?

[`ItemList`](https://schema.org/ItemList) doesnt seem apropriate. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current setup that seems best is: Collectionpage with HasPart

Answer (score 2):

If it is a list of items that have their own pages (like this), then Google does recommend ItemList with just the URLs marked up.

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/mark-up-listings

You could extend it with a name, description, additionalType etc.

It's probably more valuable (with Google) to make sure you mark up the BlogPosting pages correctly. It's a sub type of Article, so those rules apply:

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/article

Comment: thanks, could this lead to a carousel in the search results?

Comment: I think so, the guidelines specifically mentions Article is supported, and BlogPosting is a sub type of Article.

Answer (score 1):

https://schema.org/Blog for the list of posts, with the nested data type for single post https://schema.org/BlogPosting.

Make use of https://pending.schema.org/category as an https://schema.org/additionalType too.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Wordpress, the best plugin you can use for this purpose is Schema (https://wordpress.org/plugins/schema/). This article is not good if your website has products or reviews but it's good for a Blogsite, so do try it. Just install, set it up and let the plug in do the rest for you.